# Dynamic Product Price According to Number of Days Rented using Virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am considering using VirtueMart to set up a client with an easy to update e-commerce solution.  I am new to VirtueMart, and Joomla, and am really just looking for a quick easy solution to e-commerce, so I thought to check the software out.

Anyhow I have a requirement where the client lists a product for renting purposes, the price to rent varies depending on the number of days the desired product is going to be rented for.  Does anybody know of an easy way to implement this using VirtueMart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, virtuemart should be able to do what your looking for.  you can set "advanced attributes" for each product/item, and each attribute can have its own price.

So you could have say, an attribute for each rental perio, for example:
Product: "Rental A";
  Attribute 1:  1 day  - $100;
  Attribute 2:  2 days - $190;
  Attribute 3:  3 days - $270
  ...
and so on.  There are various in-built ways that you can choose to display this, but I think a dropdown menu is the simplest and cleanest.

Also bear in mind that these are static prices (i.e. need to be manually entered into the system for each product/item) -- so you won't be able to base it on a formula or calculation without some custom coding/hacking...

Hope this helps,
E